# No tool named docker found in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm using a Jenkins in a container and I'm trying to deploy a docker app using Jenkins.

I'm stuck at an error at the end of my pipeline :

```
No tool named docker found
```

Here is a part of my Jenkinsfile where the issue appear :

```
stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps{
                script {
                    def dockerHome = tool 'docker'
                    env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

I installed docker on my linux server and in my Jenkins container.

That's what I did to create my Jenkins container :

```
docker run -d --name jenkins-master -p 4800:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins:2.235.5
```

I can access to docker command in my Jenkins.
I also installed the Docker-plugin in Jenkins.

Comment: Why do you need ```tools``` for this? If you want to build a docker image, you can just simply run ```docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")```. See [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue.

I didn't configure correctly Docker in global tool configuration, in Jenkins.

[image]

It works now.